# Sample Data error

Tags: magento-1.9, media, sample-data, not-found

I'm trying to install Magento CE on Ubuntu 14.
Everything is fine but when I go in the frontend I can't see the Sample images in the right way and when I try to click on links a Not Found error appears.
What can I do?

Comment: Did you enable URL rewriting? Have you got mod_rewrite enabled?

Answer (score 0):

@Douglas is correct - you just need to get the web server doing re-writes. There is a small gotcha though, so an extra step here, to hopefully save you some time:

Step 1 - install and enable the mod_rewrite module;

Step 2 - edit the vhost configuration to allow over-rides in .htaccess;

Step 3 - restart/reload apache;

If you try and enable the apache mod_rewite module then it will let you know if it is installed:

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

In the vhost declaration (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf) you need to find the `<directory  ... >` entry and put `AllowOverride All` in there. This is what enables the htaccess file to be read and for the rewrites to be picked up correctly.